# rest service not available in jboss

Tags: java, spring, rest, jboss

I'm following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/build-rest-web-service-using-spring) to create my first REST service. Instead of tomcat I'm using jboss (6.4.14). I have generated the war without any problem and placed it into standalone/deployments directory.This is how it looks:

[image]

When I call this service (http://localhost:8081/SpringRestService/rest/payment/pay?key=SHARED_KEY) I get a 404 reponse.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /SpringRestService/rest/payment/pay</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /SpringRestService/rest/payment/pay</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>JBWEB000068: message</b>
            <u>/SpringRestService/rest/payment/pay</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>JBWEB000069: description</b>
            <u>JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how my request looks like:
[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Thank you for your time and answers, I really appreciate them.

Comment: which version of jboss is that? Do you get something in the jboss log when you deploy the war?

Comment: Did you see that the pay method in that tutorial is a POST method? And you try to access it as a GET resource?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I have to send the key in the URL but I send a JSON request in the body.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I have jBoss 6.4.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the tutorial you used for creating your first REST service : it's missing configuration of your web.xml for deploying your service into a jboss application server.

You can follow the jboss documentation to modify your web.xml : https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html